# Trigger event on right-click

Tags: layers, carto

I want to, on right-click on a feature in a layer, have an action execute. I need to know 1 thing: What layer was right-clicked. Does anybody know how I can get this functionality? The API doesn't officially support it.

Comment: ...which API???

Comment: CartoDB, sorry.

Comment: I would select an answer, but I am no longer working on that project and don't have access to that code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit weird, but did you try to catch the secondary click event using Leaflet (assuming you're not using Google Maps), and then open a popup or raise a featureClick event in your layer?

Almost pseudo-code here, but...

```
map.on('contextmenu',function(){
    // Do something to get Lat, Lng of the point
    var lat = ...;
    var lng = ...;

    var sql = cartodb.SQL({user: 'your_user'});

    // Perform this test with all your layers. Assume that 'layer' is the layer that matches your table1
    sql.execute("select cartodb_id from table1 where st_contains(the_geom, CDB_LatLng(" + lat + "," + lng + "))")

    .done(function(data) {
        if (data.rows && data.rows.length == 1) {
           // You clicked inside that layer, and got 1 point as result.

           // OPTION 1: Open a Leaflet popup
           var popup =  L.popup().setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>'); 
           popup.openOn(map); 

           // OPTION 2: Fake a normal click on the layer. 
           layer.trigger('featureClick', null, [lat, lng], null, { cartodb_id: data.rows[0].cartodb_id }, 0);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CartoDB, but have you tried checking the sender of the event or the event arguments to see if there.  You might be able to use a mouse down event, check for the right mouse button, then check the sender to see who it was that prompted the event.

Answer (score 0):

This feature may be added at some point.

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/124